# Calculating and using Euclidean Distance in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the Euclidean Distance between two datasets in python.
I can do this using the following:

```
np.linalg.norm(df-signal)
```

With `df` and `signal` being my two datasets.
This returns a single numerical value (i.e, 8258155.579535276), which is fine.
My issue is that I want it to return the difference between each column in the dataset. Something like this:

```
AFNLWGT     4.867376e+10
AGI         3.769233e+09
EMCONTRB    1.202935e+07
FEDTAX      8.095078e+07
PTOTVAL     2.500056e+09
STATETAX    1.007451e+07
TAXINC      2.027124e+09
POTHVAL     1.158428e+08
INTVAL      1.606913e+07
PEARNVAL    2.038357e+09
FICA        1.080950e+07
WSALVAL     1.986075e+09
ERNVAL      1.905109e+09
```

I'm fairly new to Python so would really appreciate any help possible.

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), you can specify the axis parameter in `np.linalg.norm`. For column-wise distance use `axis=0`.

Comment: That's returning all the numerical values, is it possible to have it similar to the desired way I mention in the question? That's what I get when I use "np.square(np.subtract(df, signal)).mean()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the columnwise norm with column headers you can use [pandas.DataFrame.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) together with `np.linalg.norm`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

norms = (df-signal).aggregate(np.linalg.norm)
```

Notice that, by default, `.aggregate` operates along the 0-axis (hence columns).

However this will be much slower than the numpy implementation:

```py
norms = pd.Series(np.linalg.norm(df.to_numpy()-signal.to_numpy(), axis=0), 
                  index=df.columns)
```

With test data of size 100x2, the latter is 20x faster.

Comment: I also added the way I would actually do it using numpy for performance.